# NonNull,Nullable,looperProto,Slog,ProtoOutputStream cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I don't know which change on my Project did this fault, I cannot run my app without fixing this problem. Here are my dependencies:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:+'
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.1'
```

In settings I searched for Not Null, it was disabled. I enabled it but it is still red.

My Looper Class:

```
import android.annotation.NonNull;
import android.annotation.Nullable;
import android.os.LooperProto;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Printer;
import android.util.Slog;
import android.util.proto.ProtoOutputStream;
```

`NonNull`,`Nullable`,`LooperProto`,`Slog`,`ProtoOutputStream` are red.

`NonNull` and `Nullable` are also red in my `Handler` Class.
Please help me I don't know, what I should do, I think I have all dependencies.

Comment: I dont know why but it runs now. I changed in my styles                   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">.  to Theme.AppCompat, now it runs all fine and I don't know why :/

Comment: added code block